# Permanently remove the Touch Keyboard icon from taskbar so it does not come back after reboot

Tags: windows, keyboard, taskbar, touch-keyboard

How can I permanently remove the Touch Keyboard icon from the taskbar so it does not come back after reboot?

I have tried the following methods without success (Touch Keyboard icon comes back after reboot).

1. Right click toolbar, un-tick Touch Keyboard
2. Disable Touch Keyboard Service

Comment: Even if you found the answer yourself, please still follow the regular "question & answer" format. Edit the question to put an actual _question_ there, and post the answer below.

Comment: Instructions on how to answer your own question can be found [here](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).  The consistent question-and-answer format that StackExchange sites enforce may seem unfamiliar to users of mailing lists.  But, this format is part of the reason why SE has been so successful as a resource for computer users.

Comment: Many thanks fixer1234 for rephrasing the OP to the correct format for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open File explorer

File explorer: navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink
File explorer: Right click TipBand.dll
File explorer: Click Properties > Properties dialogue displayed

TipBand.dll Properties: Click Security tab
TipBand.dll Properties: Click Advanced button > Advanced Security Settings dialogue displayed

Advanced Security Settings: Beside Owner at top of dialogue, click Change link >  Select User Group dialogue displayed

Select User Group: Type Everyone into object name text box
Select User Group: Click OK

Advanced Security Settings: Click OK

TipBand.dll Properties: Select Administrators
TipBand.dll Properties: Permissions - check Full control
TipBand.dll Properties: OK

File explorer: Rename TipBand.dll as TipBand.dll.bak

Taskbar: Right Click > Toolbars > Un-check Touch Keyboard
DONE!

Touch Keyboard icon will no longer show on taskbar after reboot.

To restore - rename TipBand.dll.bak as  TipBand.dll

Answer (score 0):

Just search for `Notification Area Icons` in Control Panel.
There you can adjust which icons you wan't to see and when. This is an original and safe Windows functionality.

Better not tamper with Windows libraries if you are not a programmer or at least 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: Touch Keyboard icon is not a Notification icon - it is a toolbar.
You can see other examples by right clicking the task bar and viewing the Toolbars options.